# Android ListView onItemClickListener doesn't do anything

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

i'm still a newbie programmer and i have a question for you, more expert and smart than me: currently i have a problem with the itemClickListener, i don't know why but i set all correctly but when i launch my app and try to touch an item, the listener doesn't respond, it doesn't do anything... I hope can you help me and i apologize for my english, i'm still improving it...

Also if you have any suggestion for improvment the way i write code I would be infinitely grateful!!!

Code - The Listener:

```
@Override
public void updateUI(ArrayList<Place> placeList) {

    placesFound = placeList;

    PlacesAdapter adapter = new PlacesAdapter(this, placesFound);
    placesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    placesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.d("USER", "Item clicked");
        }
    });


    if (placeList.size() == 0)
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_results_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Code - All Class:

```
public class CategoryResultsActivity extends Activity implements ChangeDataInterface {

// Take the category name from the Intent and use
// it to retrive data using the category anme itself and other parameters
// not asked to the user directly, but using defaults one.
// If the user want to change this parameters, it can with the spinners in the page
// The data retrived will be in an xml format and parsed inside this class.


// Category used to make a request to the server using it as filter, 
// get only data fpr the selected category.
private String category = "bar";

// Location used to search places of the category within a radius
// Location expressed in longitude, latitude. To retrive this informations
// it will be used a service that give this informations using a city name
// If the user want to search places using its position, the service will
// use the geolocation inside the phone.
// Order: latitude, longitude
private String  latitude  = "45.070562",
                longitude = "7.686619";

// Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return Place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters.
private String radius = "500";

// Indicates whether or not the Place request came from a device using a location sensor (e.g. a GPS) to determine the 
// location sent in this request. This value must be either true or false.
private boolean sensor = false;

// List of the places found with the parsing, keep in memory while parsing all data and,
// once all is finished, show to the user
private ArrayList<Place> placesFound = new ArrayList<Place>();

/*---------- LAYOUT DATA --------------*/

// FrameLayout - Image for the search category
private FrameLayout categoryImageFrameLayout;

// ListView - List of places found from the parsing
private ListView placesListView;

// Spinner for ordering data by the distance,
// used in this case default distance, expressed in meters, like: 
// 50m, 100m, 200m, 500m, 1km, 2km, 5km, 10km, 20km, 50km
private Spinner orderByDistanceSpinner;

// View on a map the data found, each place is reported
// on a map using a marker
private Button showOnMapButton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_results);

    // Initialize the layout data
    categoryImageFrameLayout =  (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.categoryResultsFrameLayout);
    placesListView =            (ListView)    findViewById(R.id.categoryResultsListView);
    orderByDistanceSpinner =    (Spinner)     findViewById(R.id.orderByDistanceSpinner);
    showOnMapButton =           (Button)      findViewById(R.id.showOnMapButton);

    // Get data from the intent passed and set the parameters  
    category = getDataFromIntent(getIntent());

    // Get the search category image and set it
    categoryImageFrameLayout.setBackgroundResource(getCategoryImage(category));

    // When set up spinner download also the data and refresh the UI
    setUpSpinner();

    // Set the listener for the showOnMapButton, when clicked open a new activity with
    // all the places showed on a map using markers
    showOnMapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String[] user = {latitude, longitude};

            Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryResultsActivity.this, ShowOnMapActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("places", placesFound); 
            intent.putExtra("user", user);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


// Get data from intent and set data
// The intent will contain the category name
// used in the search
private String getDataFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    return intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME);
}

// Get the image relative to the current category and return it
private int getCategoryImage(String category) {
    int image = R.drawable.all;

    if ( category.equals("restaurant") )            image = R.drawable.restaurant_header;
    else if ( category.equals("bar") )              image = R.drawable.bar_header;
    else if ( category.equals("bank") )             image = R.drawable.bank_header;
    else if ( category.equals("book_store") )       image = R.drawable.book_store_header;
    else if ( category.equals("shopping_mall") )    image = R.drawable.shopping_mall_header;
    else if ( category.equals("clothing_store") )   image = R.drawable.clothing_store_header;
    else if ( category.equals("museum") )           image = R.drawable.museum_header;
    else if ( category.equals("library") )          image = R.drawable.library_header;
    else if ( category.equals("bus_station") )      image = R.drawable.bus_station_header;
    else if ( category.equals("park") )             image = R.drawable.park_header;

    return image;
}

// Update the UI using the data passed, if no results were found
// then set the appropriate background image
@Override
public void updateUI(ArrayList<Place> placeList) {

    placesFound = placeList;

    PlacesAdapter adapter = new PlacesAdapter(this, placesFound);
    placesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    placesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.d("USER", "Item clicked");
        }
    });


    if (placeList.size() == 0)
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_results_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void setUpSpinner() {

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
            (this, R.array.distances, R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    orderByDistanceSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    orderByDistanceSpinner.setSelection(3);    // Select 500 meters as default

    orderByDistanceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> container, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // Cast the view clicked to a textview and take the text inside
            TextView textClicked = (TextView) view;
            String text = textClicked.getText().toString();

            // If the text has a km measure, then replace it with 3 zero.
            // Example:   5km => 5 000
            text = text.replace("km", "000");

            // If the text also contains a meter measure, remove it
            text = text.replace("m", "");

            // Set the new radius
            radius = text;

            // Retrive the data using an asyncTask, so we will use another thread
            // in background to download the data, and once complete, set it using the 
            // onPostExecute method.
            downloadData();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> container) {  }

    });
}

// Check if the device is connected to internet
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
            manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

// Check if the device has an internet connection. 
// Internet connection: download data and show a message to the user
// No Internet connection: Show an error message using a toast
private void downloadData() {

    // INTERNET
    if (isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.downloading_data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new PlaceSearchTask(this, category, radius, latitude, longitude, sensor).execute();
    }

    // NO INTERNET
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.internet_connection_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.category_results, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String address) {

            // Get the parameters for the address 
            List<Address> result = null;
            try {
                result = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext()).getFromLocationName(address, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Check if found results
            if (result != null) {
                // Search the results 
                latitude = result.get(0).getLatitude() + "";
                longitude = result.get(0).getLongitude() + "";
                downloadData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.address_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        return true;
    case R.id.action_geolocation:
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        longitude = location.getLongitude() + "";
        latitude = location.getLatitude() + "";
        downloadData();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



//Support for the list adapter, optimizing the speed
//keeping in memory some data
class ViewHolder {
    private FrameLayout image;
    private TextView    name,
                        vicinity;

    private RatingBar rating;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        this.image =      (FrameLayout)   view.findViewById(R.id.singleCatResultImageFrameLayout);
        this.name =       (TextView)      view.findViewById(R.id.singleCatResultTitleTextView);
        this.vicinity =   (TextView)      view.findViewById(R.id.singleCatResultAddressTextView);
        this.rating =     (RatingBar)      view.findViewById(R.id.singleCatResultRatingBar);
    }

    public FrameLayout getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public TextView getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public TextView getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }
    public RatingBar getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
}

class PlacesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Place> places;

    public PlacesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Place> places) {
        this.context = context;
        this.places =  places;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return places.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return places.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View restoreView, ViewGroup container) {
        View view = restoreView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_category_result, container, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        // Set data for the view using the holder
        holder.getImage().      setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bar_icon);
        holder.getName().       setText( places.get(index).getName() );
        holder.getVicinity().   setText( places.get(index).getVicinity() );

        String rating = places.get(index).getRating();
        if (rating != null)
            holder.getRating().     setRating( Float.parseFloat(rating) );
        else
            holder.getRating().     setRating( 0f );

        return view;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Too much code be more specific

Comment: What does updateUI override and when is it called?

Comment: The updateUI works fine, the problem is with the listener...

Answer (score 0):

use `view.setOnClickListener()` in `getView` of your `adapter` for click listener on each row.

Comment: It works and i know, but the thing that I don't understand is why the ItemCLicklistener doesn't work... However, any suggestion for improving the code style? Please, I really need some hints and I would be so grateful !!

Comment: ItemCLicklistener must be worked but I dont know what does updateUI and why override!.and i dont see a place that you call that, move that code into onCreate() and test again.and what is the meaning of `any suggestion for improving the code style?`

Comment: updateUI is a method called from another class and it is implemented using an interface, however it works perfectly, the "error" that i have is with the listener that is never called... I'll explain: the updateUI need to replace all data into the listView with others, and i need to implement a listener for the list so i can start a new activity when an item is pressed. I've already moved the code into the onCreate method and nothing changed, I've also moved the listener there, and still not works. For the last part i mean if you have any hint for improving the way I write code(eg: Indentation)